# What does "I am all yours" mean?

Tags: idioms

In the sentence

> If you can change his idea, I am all yours.

What does *I am all yours* mean?

Answer (score 8):

It's used in various settings, with different meanings.
Your example is a fairly uncommon case; it means "If you can get him to agree, **I will support you wholeheartedly**."  We don't usually use the phrase in such a serious manner.

More commonly, it's used when people are making social/entertainment plans; in that case, it means "I'm ready / I'm not busy (or don't have other plans) at the moment / your suggestion sounds good to me":
"Are you ready to go?"  "**I'm all yours.**"
"Bob, do you have a minute to go over the sales numbers?"  "**I'm all yours.**"
"Want to meet for drinks after work?"  "**I'm all yours**."

If you're not familiar with the idiom, this phrase can sound a lot more meaningful than it's usually meant to be - be careful not to read too much into it!

Comment: In the sense of "I'm not busy" I would rather say "You have my undivided attention"; +1 for last paragraph

Comment: @Unreason - It's not one of my favorite phrases in any connotation (although I must confess that I say it once in a while) - there are definitely better substitutes for each sense, unless you really are using it in a romantic / metaphysical sense!  I didn't meant the above as a *usage* recommendation, more as a guide to understanding what it means when you hear it.  Personally, my favorite response to "Do you have a minute?" is from *American Beauty* - "For you, Brad, I've got **five**."

Answer (score 2):

I'm all yours means, I'm at your disposal (= I am ready to help you in any way I can).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not native speaker but I'd say it depends on context here, for example:

> If you can get him to agree, I'll go with you with pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

MT_Head is correct.  It's means "You have my full attention" with a mildly saucy double entendre.  Tone of voice is important, as the statement can be as bland or as racy as you'd wish.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is a more of a comment on an existing answer than it is an answer it its own right. Once you gain a bit more reputation by asking or answering questions, you will be able to comment in your own right. Until then, please use the Answer button to supply only your own new answers, not comments on others’ answers.

Answer (score -2):

I mildly disagree.  I've always heard the phrase used more in the context of romantic relationships.
"Do you really like me?"
"I'm all yours."

"Would you like to go out sometime?"
"I'm all yours."

Comment: So what does it mean?