# Meaning of "enjoy me"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct English to answer the question "are you free now?" with "enjoy me" and if it is correct, would it have more than one meaning?

I asked someone at work (face-to-face) if they were free to discuss a subject and they gave that answer, so was wondering if it even existed, since English was their native language and not mine.

Comment: That sounds completely wrong to me. Why not just "Yes"? I don't even understand what your example means . . .

Comment: I asked someone at work if they were free to discuss a subject and they gave that answer, so was wondering if it even existed, since English was their native language and not mine.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say "entertain me"? That would make sense - "enjoy me" does not.

Comment: I agree with other answers posted below, and In my opinion, if someone asks question "are you free now?" I would reply saying "Yes, I am" or "No, i am not". N this just just a guess, in case you want to say that you are enjoying your time, then you can say "Yes, I am free and enjoying my time"

Comment: What medium was being used with this interaction? Could the answer be a mistake caused by something like autocorrect on a smartphone?

Comment: the interaction was face to face, which confused me, so yes sure he said "enjoy me".. and yes this is what I wondered why didn't he just say: Yes I am free lol.. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say "*join* me" or something else that sounds similar like that?

Comment: Positive.. if they had said Join me it would not have been confusing.. but since its confusing a lot of the members, then its good to know it was fine to be confused :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

A common answer to your question could be "I'm all yours", which essentially means "Yes, I am ready now." (See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31839/what-does-i-am-all-yours-mean) link for more examples of "I'm all yours")

I could see extending this phrase as a joke, "I'm all yours. Enjoy me!" The "Enjoy me!" being added to point out a possible double entendre of "I'm all yours."

Finally, this person has been using this "joke" for so long, that they have evolved the joke to the shortened non-sensical phrase "Enjoy me!"

Perhaps they do not even realize that their response is non-sensical because they still have the connections to the original version in their own memory.

Comment: interesting explanation.. makes a lot of sense too.. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that "enjoy me" is correct, it sounds awkward and maybe even sexual, I think "Yes" would be a better answer for "Are you free now?"

Comment: so same as comment above "I asked someone at work if they were free to discuss a subject and they gave that answer, so was wondering if it even existed, since English was their native language and not mine. "

Comment: Yes, I very much doubt it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Kalm it's grammatically correct.

Comment: @aesking right, but semantically it makes no sense in this context

Comment: @rosslh right, and what is the context? We don't know the full context. If we did, it could be grammatically and semantically acceptable, which is why I don't like sweeping statements. Context is key.

Comment: @aesking We have the context.  OP asked someone at work face-to-face "Are you free now?".  This is a professional atmosphere, clearly asking if someone is available (presumably for something work related).  In that context, the reply "Enjoy me" makes absolutely no sense.  The *only* way I can think of off the top of my head where the phrase "Enjoy me" would make any sense is sexually, and even then the phrase would be awkward.  Or maybe one of those M&M commercials where the M&Ms talk?

Comment: @Doc Please read my comment: I said *full* context not nill. There is some context but incomplete: was the person talking to them? etc. but it may be an idiomatic way of saying, "Enjoy me = Enjoy the presence of my now free time." I'm sorry, if the only context you'd think where it would be plausible would be sexually; the expression may be more innocent than it seems. **In fact, personally I think the best answer on here realises the expression is "ambiguous" rather than attributing a notion to something that wasn't there to begin with.** As you said it's a work environment

Answer (score 1):

`Enjoy me` seems ambiguous. What exactly do you want to say? `Enjoying my time` maybe?

Comment: please see above comment.. and many thanks to all for the responses

Comment: Couldn't find this term in any documents so I think the best way is to ask that person directly.

Comment: I suspect that the person who said 'enjoy me' was making a joke.

Comment: I think this is what it was.. though I don't understand the Joke :)

Comment: Possibly what we in Britain call 'workplace banter'. Lighthearted jocular small talk.  A different way of saying "Yes, I am free; you may ask me to do something for you". Older British people will remember a TV series called "Are You Being Served?" where "Are you free?" was often said, and became a catch-phrase.

Comment: “Enjoying my time” doesn’t really make sense as a response here, either.

Comment: Well, if by "ambiguous" you mean it could be either "have sex with me" or "eat me", then yeah I suppose you could call it ambiguous. Other than that, it's not ambiguous at all but rather blunt indeed.

Comment: @regdwigнt Why are people so quick to attribute a possibly innocent expression for "Enjoy my free time because I don't have a lot" and quickly attributing it to a phallic symbol or sex. Yes people do that. But I think it's best to assume the more plausible explanation. Saying "enjoy me" to "are you free now?" to mean have sex or "eat me" is the least unlikely, plausible explanation. If it were meant to be a joke or "banter" I wouldn't get it as the 'the joke' is so subtle to the point of negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking more context, it might have been meant in a flirty or joking way to say that they are free.
You could compare it to "Yes, enjoy the time with me.", but in an even less formal way.

It is syntactically correct, but not in common use and depends on the context.

Comment: so yes, this what it was I guess, a joke (although I didn't find it funny lol) or a flirt.. but I was confused and it felt awkward, and really wanted to understand what this person meant, making sure I did not misunderstand him. thanks a lot for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, this is not a common phrase or a standard response or anything of the sort. As a native English speaker, that response would surprise and confuse me. If the speaker was non-native, I’d write it off as maybe a too-literal translation from their language or something, but if the speaker was also a native speaker of English, I’d be rather perplexed. I would suspect it’s a joke or a reference to something, but I’m not familiar with whatever might be referenced here.

I cannot think of any circumstance in which I would use this phrase. As others have noted, it sounds like it might be sexual—though still highly awkward and non-standard. As if the speaker was attempting to flirt but with a weaker grasp of the language, maybe. But certainly not one I would use, or expect another native speaker to use, even in a sexual situation.

Between it being awkward and unusual, and seeming possibly sexual, I strongly discourage you from using it, particularly around the workplace.

Comment: thanks for the insight.. he was a native and I am not (but fluent) so assumed it might be slang. well noted will never use it ;)